# Python - how does a variable from this function progress through a dictionary?

Tags: python, concept

I am having difficulty understanding one part of the code below. I was able to get it correct in an online lesson, so I'm not looking for help finishing it, just understanding this: in the last segment of code, I'm confused about how the **x** and **food** work. How is the x going through the items in prices?

```
shopping_list = ["banana", "orange", "apple"]

stock = {
  "banana": 6,
  "apple": 0,
  "orange": 32,
  "pear": 15
}

prices = {
  "banana": 4,
  "apple": 2,
  "orange": 1.5,
  "pear": 3
}

def compute_bill(food):
  total = 0
  for x in food:
    total = total + prices[x]
  return total
```

Comment: Which part do you not understand? How `for` loops work in Python or how items in `dictionary` are accessed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python `dictionaries` (and other python data structures) implement what is called an [`iterator` pattern](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0234/#dictionary-iterators), which takes one item at a time, in order, untill it traverses the whole data structure.

> Dictionaries implement a tp_iter slot that returns an efficient
>   iterator that iterates over the keys of the dictionary. During such an
>   iteration, the dictionary should not be modified, except that setting
>   the value for an existing key is allowed (deletions or additions are
>   not, nor is the update() method). This means that we can write
>
> `for k in dict: ...`
>
> which is equivalent to, but much faster than
>
> `for k in dict.keys(): ...`
>
> as long as the restriction on modifications to the dictionary (either
>   by the loop or by another thread) are not violated.

The code: `for x in food:` simply inits the `iterator` in the python `dict` and calls it repeatedly to get the next item untill the last item.

That is how it works in python (and other languages as well). Python knows internaly that the `dict` implements an `iterator` and `for` loops call this iterator underneath.

Comment: Oh okay, thank you! I was confused at how it knew to send x through the price list.

Answer (score 0):

`prices` is a dictionary, a mapping of keys (banana, apple, ...) to values (4, 2, ...).

`for x in food` means "For every item in the provided list called `food`, give it a temporary variable assignment `x` and do something with `x`."

`total = total + prices[x]` means "Assign the current value of `total` added to the price of item `x` (looked up from prices)". For the first item in `food` (banana in  this case), you're looking for a corresponding price in `prices` (which is 4). So, you're really saying `total = 0 + 4`, then moving onto the next item in `food`. Since `total` is now set to 4, your assignment becomes `total = 4 + price['orange']`, or `4 + 1.5`. Once the list has been iterated entirely, you have a `total` sum (7.5 in your example).